# What does the mortar and pestle Safari address bar icon indicate

Tags: safari, address-bar

I just noticed that there is a mortar and pestle icon that shows up in Safari on my iPad when I open my smartmail.com web page and was wondering if anyone knows what it means?

Its in the same location as the font icon, left side of the address bar, and is only shown while the page is loading. I haven't seen it on other pages.  Any insight would be appreciated.

[image: Unknown Icon]

Comment: What you have circled are a pair of speech-bubbles that seem to be indicating a **choice of language** using English and Chinese characters purely as examples. I'm unsure what you mean by "mortal and pistol" - you can't mean *[mortar and pestle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mortar_and_pestle)* but I'm struggling to find anything that matches your phrase.

Comment: If you click the icon, does a language selection/translation list appear?

Comment: Cross site duplicate [What are the two symbols in the Google Translate icon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29114113/what-are-the-two-symbols-in-the-google-translate-icon)

Comment: Yes, I meant mortar

Comment: @spikey_richie it happens very fast but if I’m quick it brings up a translation dialog

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick in the foremost bubble, the character looks like a pestle and mortar.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_Icon

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The "pestle and mortar" icon is a Chinese character. It is [apparently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29114113/what-are-the-two-symbols-in-the-google-translate-icon) the Chinese character for "text" or "article".

The icon represents one person speaking English while another is speaking in Chinese. It is an often used icon style for translation services such as Google Translate and Apples equivalent. It will translate the page for you.

Comment: I’m fairly sure it’s but the icon for Google Translate given that it’s in the Safari browser. This uses Apple’s translation service, not Google’s.

Comment: @Tim fixed and made more generic

Comment: For the etymology of the 文 character see [here](https://hanziyuan.net/#%E6%96%87) or [here](https://www.zdic.net/hans/%E6%96%87)